# Auto installing wkhtmltopdf using composer on a server

Tags: centos, composer-php, wkhtmltopdf, whm

Has anyone been successful in using wkhtmltopdf with composer? I currently have wkhtmltopdf installed on my server (centos running whm) but I'm trying to find a way that these packages install automatically should I need to move the website to another server. I've only just started looking into composer in the last couple of weeks and aren't sure of how capable it is.

Wkhtmltopdf is currently invoked via joomla cms as a shell exec script.

Can anyone share their story on how you overcame this?

Comment: Some seconds of googling pointed me to https://github.com/h4cc/wkhtmltopdf-amd64 - is this what you are looking for? If not, please clarify your question

Comment: Hi Nico, thanks for coming back to me. Yes i does look like the one that I'm after. I really haven't stepped into composer before and thus aren't that confident which is why I was asking if anyone has implemented it in their project. I'll try the url out and see how I go. Thanks Nico.